# Passing data from Recycler view onClick to Detail Activity with android databinding

Tags: android, android-fragments, data-binding, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a list of items populating through recyclerview with android databinding technique and now I want to pass and populate the same data in detail Activity not getting the right thing to do such. So, kindly help to do this.

public class Fragment extends Fragment {

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private Firebase mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xyz.firebaseio.com/category/").child("list");

public Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<List, ViewHolder>List.class, R.layout.fragment,
            ViewHolder.class, mFirebaseRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, List list, int i) {

            FragmentBinding binding = viewHolder.getBinding();
            binding.setList(list);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));
    return rootView;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public FragmentBinding binding;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public FragmentBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailedActivity.class);

        **// need help here**

        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}


@BindingAdapter("quantity")
public static void setQuantityText(TextView view, int quantity) {
    view.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
}
public static class Handlers {

    public  static void increment(View view, int max) {
        FragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(view);
        binding.setQuantity(Math.max(max, binding.getQuantity() + 1));
    }
    public static void decrement(View view, int min) {
        FragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(view);
        binding.setQuantity(Math.min(min, binding.getQuantity() - 1));
    }
}
```

}

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="List"
        type="com.xyz.www.android.model.List"/>

    <variable
        name="quantity"
        type="int"/>

    <variable
        name="Handlers"
        type="com.xyz.www.android.ui.fragments.Fragment.Handlers"/>

</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="76dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            app:imageUrl="@{List.productImageUrl}"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{List.productTitle}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            app:font="@{`Roboto-Regular.ttf`}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{List.productSku}"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            app:font="@{`Roboto-Regular.ttf`}"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Rs"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                android:paddingStart="2dp"
                app:font="@{`Roboto-Regular.ttf`}"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{List.productSellingPrice}"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="2dp"
                android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                app:font="@{`Roboto-Regular.ttf`}"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">


        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/decrease" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:font="@{`Roboto-Regular.ttf`}"
            app:quantity="@{quantity}"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/increase" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

public class List extends BaseObservable {

```
String productTitle;
String productSku;
String productImageUrl;
String productDescription;
String productMrp;
String productSellingPrice;


public List() {
}

public List(String productTitle, String productSku,
                 String productImageUrl, String productDescription,
                 String productMrp, String productSellingPrice) {

    this.productTitle = productTitle;
    this.productSku = productSku;
    this.productImageUrl = productImageUrl;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
    this.productMrp = productMrp;
    this.productSellingPrice = productSellingPrice;

}

@Bindable
public String getProductTitle() {
    return productTitle;
}

@Bindable
public String getProductSku() {
    return productSku;
}

@Bindable
public String getProductImageUrl() {
    return productImageUrl;
}

@Bindable
public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

@Bindable
public String getProductMrp() {
    return productMrp;
}

@Bindable
public String getProductSellingPrice() {
    return productSellingPrice;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use a class name as List. It is not a good practice of Coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. One is to make List Parcelable so that you can pass it as an Intent extra. You'll then be able to extract it and populate the Detail page.

```
public static final LIST = "ListContent";
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailedActivity.class);

    FragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(v);
    intent.putExtra(LIST, binding.getList());

    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Another is to pass only the ID for the List and read the information again in the detail binding. Add the ID to the List and then you'll be able to extract it when you start the activity:

```
public static final LIST_ID = "ListID";
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailedActivity.class);

    FragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(v);
    intent.putExtra(LIST_ID, binding.getList().getId());

    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Either way, you can pull the data from the intent in the onCreate of your details Activity:

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Using ID:
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(LIST_ID);
    List list = loadListFromId(id);

    // Using Parcelable:
    List list = intent.getParcelableExtra(LIST);
    //...
}
```